# Failed to install Tweepy (extreme beginner)

Tags: tweepy

I have a feeling I will feel pretty dumb about this but I'm running out of options. In my defense, I am just starting my coding experience.

I just set up my VS Code and want to try building a Twitter bot using Python but I am failing to install Tweepy...
I set up my main.py file, I run "pip install tweepy" in terminal, but it gives me back:

pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pip install tweepy
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I set up my main.py file, I run "pip install tweepy" but instead of proceeding, it gave me an error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like pip isn't installed on your system. Have you [installed it](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)?

Comment: It seems so. I ran ''py -m ensurepip --upgrade'' and it shows:

Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\...
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\...

Another note is that the terminal is showing to me C:... (file location) before the prompt I can enter. In other places I saw it is ''$". Could that has to do with something?